# Write a type for a function that takes a number and returns a string In TypeScript

Tags: typescript, function, types

I have this problem and I don't know what my error is?

Write a type for a function that takes a number and returns a string.

https://www.executeprogram.com/courses/typescript/quizzes/writing-a-function-type

This is my code

```
type TakesNumberReturnsString = number
const numberToString = (x: TakesNumberReturnsString) => {
  return x.toString
}
```

These are the results

This is the error

```
>

function add1AndAppend1(x: number): string {
  return (x + 1).toString() + 1
}
const f: TakesNumberReturnsString = add1AndAppend1
f(1)

Expected: '21' but got: type error: type error: Type '(x: number) => string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

These are the good results

````
>

function add1AndAppend1(x: number): string {
  return (x + 1).toString() + 1
}
const f: TakesNumberReturnsString = add1AndAppend1
f("hello")

Expected: type error: Argument of type '"hello"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. OK!
>

function sayHello(x: undefined): string {
  return 'hello'
}
const f: TakesNumberReturnsString = sayHello
f(undefined)

Expected: type error: Type '(x: undefined) => string' is not assignable to type 'TakesNumberReturnsString'. OK!
>

function add1(x: number): string {
  return x + 1
}
const f: TakesNumberReturnsString = add1
f(1)

Expected: type error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. OK!
4 tests, 1 failure```
````

Comment: If `TakesNumberReturnsString` is supposed to be the type of a function, why have you defined it to be  `number`?  By the way, the error message `Type '(x: number) => string' is not assignable to type 'number'.` is telling you exactly what the problem is.  Given that this is a quiz to show that you've learned TS, I suggest you go back and review the material.  Not sure if writing up an answer would be satisfying if it circumvents the learning that should be happening.

Comment: @Héctor they're not asking you to write a function, they're asking you to write a type. So you won't write a `const numberToString = /* something */`, you'll just write `type TakesNumberReturnsString = /* something */`

Comment: ok, now I understand what they mean, but if I put the following combinations:

`type TakesNumberReturnsString = any`
1- 0k
2- bad
3- bad
4- ok

`type TakesNumberReturnsString = number`
1- **Expected: '21' but got: type error: type error: Type '(x: number) => string' is not assignable to type 'number'.**

`type TakesNumberReturnsString = string`
1- **Expected: '21' but got: type error: type error: Type '(x: number) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.**

Thank you for your help, but really I'm confused

Comment: **Update** - I just passed the lesson, but the bad thing is that it was not because I knew it, I was researching in the documentation of the Typescript web page and I put this 'type TakesNumberReturnsString = (i: number) => void;' and pass the lesson.